# NumberFormatter turn percent value to double get nil

Tags: ios, swift

I want to turn `String` precent value into `Double` by:

```
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .percent
        let a = formatter.number(from: "12.5%")
        print(a)
```

It works well in playground. But when test in project under "romana"(Română) language, it prints `nil`. If i change 12.5% to int type percentage value like `56%` it works no problem.

Any idea?

Attached the language setting page.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .percent
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "EN")
let a = formatter.number(from: "12.5%")
```

Answer (score 4):

> If i change 12.5% to int type percentage value like 56% it works no problem.

This usually means that the locale settings use a different character for decimal separator, i.e. comma `,` instead of dot `.`

Switching to `12,5%` should fix this problem.

> I got all the source number with `.` separator

If your numbers are hard-coded in the source, you should not rely on user-selected locale. Use [`system` locale](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nslocale/1407691-system) for dealing with hard-coded inputs:

```
formatter.locale = Locale.system
```

> [`Locale.system` is] The generic locale that contains fixed “backstop” settings that provide values for otherwise undefined keys. Use the system locale when you don’t want any localizations.

Comment: It works. I upvoted your answer. I think the accepted answer is better. Thank you!

Comment: @WilliamHu The problem with the accepted answer is that it defeats the purpose of locales by forcing foreign numbering conventions on Romanian end-users: they will have no idea why your program is not taking a perfectly legal `12,5%`.

Comment: Thank you. You know i got all the source number with ```.``` separator. I think you mean i should replace the `.` to ```,``` in the string first. Then convert to double? But if so I am worry if some other languages use other separators. I can replace one by one? What do you think? I agree with your thoughts. But for solving my issue i chosen that answer. : ) Also realized if use this ```formatter.decimalSeparator = "."``` it works too.